# Running PostgreSQL function on specific date of each month

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I use PostgreSQL database. I have a problem where I need to update my database table on 1st day of each month. I have been doing some research on how to do it and this far I have only found that using Triggers could be a solution.

Problem with triggers is that they can be triggered only on certain events. Those events are: `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `TRUNCATE`.

Since those are only possible events of triggering a function the question is how I can trigger a function based on date? It is important to notice that I don't want to give fixed date for trigger because obviously it would be triggered on that specific date only.

Comment: You need to create a `cron` job and then run your SQL statements through that. Postgres has no built-in scheduler

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for this I'm currently checking information about cron jobs and it looks promising this far.

Comment: If postgreSQL is running on Windows you can use Windows Task Scheduler. Cron is for Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgAgent runs as a daemon on *nix systems, and a service on Windows systems

http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent-install.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is better solution in this case than cronjobs. Good article that I found about pgAgent and how to setup scheduled job can be found here http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/19-Setting-up-PgAgent-and-Doing-Scheduled-Backups.html

Comment: I made a test job and it succeeded and worked as I wanted. I highly recommend using pgAgent if you are using PostgreSQL and want to have scheduled jobs. It's pretty easy to setup everything in pgAgent but documentation could be more detailed in their website.